# Change code to use selection to fill an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code, that does what it's supposed to do. 
I would just like to change how the `myStrings` variable is filled.

From:

`myStrings = Array("Test23", "Test-12", "54-Test")`

To:

`myStrings = Selection.Value`

If I run this I get a runtime error 9; Subscript out of range.

The goal is to select some cells with text, always the same column, just different rows, and the VBA macro should delete all rows with that text in every worksheet from the workbook.

I'm new to VBA and I combined this from different sources, I can't figure out how to fix this error.

I appreciate any help or maybe even a different solution if it does the same thing.

Thank you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughWorksheets()

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Dim calcmode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim myStrings As Variant
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim myRng As Range

     Set myRng = sh.Range("A:N")

     myStrings = Array("Test23", "Test-12", "54-Test")

With Application
    calcmode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

       With sh

        .Select

        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView


        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

            With myRng

            For I = LBound(myStrings) To UBound(myStrings)
                Do
                    Set FoundCell = myRng.Find(What:=myStrings(I), _
                                               After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                               MatchCase:=False)
                    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                Loop
            Next I

        End With

    End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = calcmode
End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode

Next sh

MsgBox ("Completed")

End Sub
```

Comment: When you load from the worksheet the array is always a two dimensional array.  Even if you have only one column or row.  You need to treat it as such.

Comment: Note that you can transpose it to turn it back to 1D.

Comment: Note that Transpose is an expensive operation and unnecessary and only returns 1D array if a single column is Selected.   Just add the second dimension reference as Scott said.  Regardless, you should check the shape of Selection range before  proceeding,  you never know what your users may do...